# Syntax errors in sybase query

Tags: sql, t-sql, sybase

I have never used sybase before until today.  I have a query in Access that is using First() and has multiple iif statements.  I hoped for the best and pasted my query in and I am getting errors on the First() section.  I removed the First's from the query, and I am getting errors on the iif statements.

Here is my query:

```
SELECT Client.ClientId, First(Trans.SysId) AS FirstOfSysId, Client.Name1,
Relation.Name1, Debtor.Name1, Account.AcctId, First(Trans.PostDate) AS FirstOfPostDate,
Sum(IIf([TransType]="uc",[Amount],IIf([TransType]="CA",[Amount],IIf([TransType]="RAC",
[Amount],IIf([TransType]="UCBR",[Amount],[amount]*-1))))) AS TransAmount, 
Trans.CheckId,Relation.RelId
FROM (((Trans INNER JOIN Account ON Trans.SysAcctId = Account.SysId) 
INNER JOIN Debtor ON Account.SysDtrId = Debtor.SysId) 
INNER JOIN Relation ON Account.SysRelId = Relation.SysId) INNER JOIN Client ON
Relation.SysClientId = Client.SysId
WHERE (((Trans.TransType)="CA" Or (Trans.TransType)="NC" Or (Trans.TransType)="UC" Or
(Trans.TransType)="AC" 
Or (Trans.TransType)="UCB" Or (Trans.TransType)="RAC" Or (Trans.TransType)="UCB" Or
(Trans.TransType)="UCBR"))
GROUP BY Client.ClientId, Client.Name1, Relation.Name1, Debtor.Name1, Account.AcctId, 
Trans.CheckId, Relation.RelId
HAVING (((Client.ClientId)=[Forms]![frmCredit]![Combo112])
AND ((Sum(IIf([TransType]="uc",[Amount],IIf([TransType]="CA",[Amount],
IIf([TransType]="RAC", [Amount],IIf([TransType]="UCBR",[Amount],[amount]*-1))))))>0 
Or (Sum(IIf([TransType]="uc",[Amount],IIf([TransType]="CA",[Amount],
IIf([TransType]="RAC", [Amount],IIf([TransType]="UCBR",[Amount],[amount]*-1))))))<0)
AND ((Relation.RelId) Not Like "281099"))
ORDER BY Relation.Name1, Account.AcctId, Trans.CheckId
```

**[Edit] A more readable query has been added to http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4b98e0/1 [/Edit]**

I can't find documentation on converting the first function, but with the IIF should I convert that to a Case when statement?  I saw an article [here](http://nntp-archive.sybase.com/nntp-archive/action/article/%3CoTf$%23yUS%23GA.209@forums.powersoft.com%3E), but I am not sure if it is the most efficient, since it is from 1999...

The error I am getting is `Syntax error near 'FIRST' on line 1.` Which based on the article [here](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc01031.0400/doc/html/swa1258558261531.html) I am using it in the right syntax.

Any help on using First in the right syntax and if I should use a Case When instead of the iif is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on what I think the query does I think you can rewrite it as below. I don't have access to any Sybase server to validate the query, so I tried it on MS SQL but I commented out some stuff with /* */ that might not be needed with Sybase.

**It might be completely wrong, or it might be correct.** If it's wrong, please let me know in a comment and I'll remove my answer.

```
SELECT 
    Client.ClientId, 
    FIRST_VALUE(Trans.SysId) /* OVER (ORDER BY Trans.Sysid) */ AS FirstOfSysId, 
    Client.Name1,
    Relation.Name1, 
    Debtor.Name1, 
    Account.AcctId, 
    FIRST_VALUE(Trans.PostDate) /* OVER (ORDER BY Trans.postdate) */ AS FirstOfPostDate,
    SUM(CASE 
          WHEN [TransType] IN ('uc', 'CA', 'RAC', 'UCBR') THEN AMOUNT 
          ELSE AMOUNT * -1 
       END
       ) AS TransAmount, 
    Trans.CheckId,
    Relation.RelId
FROM Trans 
INNER JOIN Account ON Trans.SysAcctId = Account.SysId
INNER JOIN Debtor ON Account.SysDtrId = Debtor.SysId 
INNER JOIN Relation ON Account.SysRelId = Relation.SysId
INNER JOIN Client ON Relation.SysClientId = Client.SysId

WHERE Trans.TransType IN ('CA','NC','UC','AC','UCB','RAC','UCB','UCBR')

GROUP BY 
    Client.ClientId, Client.Name1, 
    Relation.Name1, Debtor.Name1, 
    Account.AcctId, Trans.CheckId, 
    Relation.RelId /* , trans.sysid, trans.postdate */

HAVING 
    1=1 --AND (((Client.ClientId)=[Forms]![frmCredit]![Combo112])
    AND SUM(
          CASE WHEN [TransType] IN ('uc', 'CA', 'RAC', 'UCBR') THEN AMOUNT 
          ELSE AMOUNT * -1 END
          ) <> 0 
    AND Relation.RelId <> '281099'

ORDER BY Relation.Name1, Account.AcctId, Trans.CheckId
```

My reasoning here is that

```
Sum(IIf([TransType]="uc",[Amount],IIf([TransType]="CA",[Amount],IIf([TransType]="RAC",
[Amount],IIf([TransType]="UCBR",[Amount],[amount]*-1))))) AS TransAmount,
```

just takes the`amount`if`TransType`is any of`'uc', 'CA', 'RAC', 'UCBR'`else`Amount*-1` and this should be equivalent with:

```
SUM(CASE WHEN [TransType] IN ('uc', 'CA', 'RAC', 'UCBR') THEN AMOUNT 
        ELSE AMOUNT*-1 END) AS TransAmount,
```

and in the`having`clause this:

```
((Sum(IIf([TransType]="uc",[Amount],IIf([TransType]="CA",[Amount],
IIf([TransType]="RAC", [Amount],IIf([TransType]="UCBR",[Amount],[amount]*-1))))))>0 
Or (Sum(IIf([TransType]="uc",[Amount],IIf([TransType]="CA",[Amount],
IIf([TransType]="RAC", [Amount],IIf([TransType]="UCBR",[Amount],[amount]*-1))))))<0)
```

just checks if the expression (`sum(amount)`) is either`> 0`or`< 0`and this should be equivalent with:

```
SUM(CASE WHEN [TransType] IN ('uc', 'CA', 'RAC', 'UCBR') THEN AMOUNT 
        ELSE AMOUNT*-1 END) <> 0
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I copied the code, and I was getting an error for the AS in the lines with the `FIRST_VALUE`.  I removed the FIRST_VALUE and added those columns to my group by and it seems to work.  Is there anything I can do to get the `FIRST` or `FIRST_VALUE` to work?

Comment: @JohnJanssen It might be that Sybase don't recognize the comment /* ... */ so you could try to remove that part, or maybe just remove the comment part and keep the `over (order ...)`part.

Comment: I removed the comments the first time and it caused the errors.  I tried removing the comment around the `over (order ...)` and ran the query with the results I was expecting.  I appreciate your help.  Thanks.